# Matching part of a string using a Perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, substring

In the variable `$hobbit` I have stored value "Emulex LPe16000".
Now I need a regular expression to match the "LPe16000" part of the value after "Emulex".
Please ignore any syntax errors,I am a novice at perl..!

```
$hobbit="Emulex LPe16000"
if ($hobbit = ~m/Emulex ^\w+$/)
    print "lol";
```

Comment: `^` means "the beginning of the string". It needs to be before `Emulex`. Then you can put `\w+` in a capturing group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^` means asserting the start of the string. If you move it to the start you could match `Emulex` followed by a space and make use of `\K` to forget what was matched.

Then match 1+ word characters `\w+` and assert the end of the string `$`

```
^Emulex \K\w+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l6z2sb/1) | [Perl demo](https://ideone.com/alhhmK)

If you want to print the match, your code might look like:

```
my $hobbit="Emulex LPe16000";
if ($hobbit =~ m/^Emulex \K\w+$/) {
    print $&;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\K` is much better way to do it, yet this expression might also work:

```
Emulex\s+([A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+)
```

#### Test

```
use strict;

my $str = 'Emulex LPe16000';
my $regex = qr/Emulex\s+([A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+)/mp;
my $subst = '$1';

my $result = $str =~ s/$regex/$subst/rg;

print $result\n";
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/HsOxcK/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/HsOxcK/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.